# Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Tags: python-3.x

```
In [458]: type(obj_xml)
Out[458]: builtins.bytes

In [459]: with codecs.open( xmlOutFile, "+ab", "utf-8" ) as f:
   .....:     f.write(obj_xml)
   .....:
```

error i am hitting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-459-61a3d9d572a6> in <module>()
      1 with codecs.open( xmlOutFile, "+ab", "utf-8" ) as f:
----> 2     f.write(obj_xml)
      3

C:\Python3\lib\codecs.py in write(self, data)
    698     def write(self, data):
    699
--> 700         return self.writer.write(data)
    701
    702     def writelines(self, list):

C:\Python3\lib\codecs.py in write(self, object)
    354         """ Writes the object's contents encoded to self.stream.
    355         """
--> 356         data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
    357         self.stream.write(data)
    358
```

TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
How do i go about writing the contents of obj_xml to the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`codecs.open` takes a Unicode string and encodes it to bytes when writing.  You already have a bytes object, so just open file file in binary mode and write the object:

```
with open(xmlOutFile,'+ab') as f:
     f.write(obj_xml)
```